# ¿Para qué sirven las llaves del string?

Tags: c#, interpolacion

```
using System;

namespace lession_9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           for (int x = 10; x < 15; x++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Value of x: {0}",x);
           }
           Console.ReadKey();
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: estas componiendo un string.. las llaves se usan como posiciones para meter alli los valores que siguen a la coma....

Comment: Es decir, @gbianchi que se puede imprimir de este modo ? -> `"Value of {0} with {1} and {2} then {3}", x, y, z`

Comment: exatamente.. y tambien como interpolacion de strings... y tambien concatenando...

Comment: gracias, entendi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los números dentro de las llaves son parámetros que serán sustituidos por los valores que tu indiques, en tu ejemplo tienes:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value of x: {0}", x);
```

Lo cual quiere decir que en el **parámetro {0}** cuando se imprima la cadena será sustituido por el contenido de la **variable x**, que en tu caso es un número(pero puede ser cualquier tipo de datos, tal como una fecha), por lo que pudieras tener algo como : Value of x: 1, suponiendo que el valor de x sea 1, usar esta forma de imprimir cadenas tiene muchas fortalezas, sino lo hicieras así tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value of x: "  + x.ToString());
```

Como ves aplicar una cadena formateada hace al código mas legible, además de que es más rápido que usar la concatenación de cadenas, imagínate que tendrías algo como esto:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value of x: {0} y es {1}{2}{3}", x, "positivo", "grande", "par");
```

Te imaginas el enredo de usar la concatenación en algo como esto:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value of x: "  + x.ToString() + "positivo" + "grande" + "par")
```

Además, usando la concatenación con el **operador +** se desperdicia memoria, ya que en **C** las cadenas son inmutables, lo cual quiere decir, que cuando concatenas en realidad estás creando un nuevo valor en otra posición de memoria sin destruir la cadena que tenías antes, es decir si tienes una cadena que dice "hola" y la concatenas con "mundo", "hola" + "mundo", el no sobreescribe la cadena original, sino que la deja y crea otra nueva cadena en algún lugar de la memoria con la nueva cadena "hola mundo", te imaginas si tuvieras que concatenar muchas veces, sería un gran desperdicio de memoria, además, hay otras fortalezas, puedes formatear en formato de monedas, horas, y otros tipos de datos, te recomiendo que investigues el **método Format()** de la **clase string**.

Comment: Muy buena explicacion

Comment: Me surge otra duda, como podria hacer ese mismo ejercicio con un WHILE?

Comment: De acuerdo,es que soy nueva usando esto, pero ya estoy viendo como funciona cada cosa

Answer (score 4):

Esto se conoce como formato compuesto de caden.
Por ejemplo:

```
String nombre = "juanito";
Integer edad = 22;

Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es {0} y tengo {1} años",nombre, edad);
```

Si te fijas bien, nombre y edad se le pasan como parametros al WriteLine al final.
en la cadena el va a buscar el parametro 0, el encuentra que el parametro 0 es nombre,
igual va a buscar el parametro 1 , y va a encontrar el valor de edad.

En otras palabras en vez de esto:

```
Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es "+nombre+"y tengo "+edad+" años");
```

haces esto:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es {0} y tengo {1} años",nombre, edad);
```

Comment: No, eso no es interpolación de cadenas.

Comment: Me surge otra duda, como podria hacer ese mismo ejercicio con un WHILE?

Answer (score 1):

Atendiendo a tu nueva duda de como se haría con un **while**, hago esta nueva respuesta para ti,

Con un **while** sería lo mismo, solo que esta vez el contador lo tendrías que manejar tu:

```
int i = 10;

while(i <= 15)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Value of i: {0}",i);
   i++;
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Como ves aquí eres tú quien se encarga de aumentar la variable que sirve para iterar.

Comment: La salida de tu respuesta seria 10, en cambio con el FOR seria del 10 hasta el 14.

Comment: Disculpa es que me confundí al escribir, ya lo arreglé, ahora si imprime del 10 al 15

Answer (score 0):

Pasa por el formato de cadena.

```
String nombre = "Eric";
Integer edad = 25;

Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es {0} y tengo {1} años",nombre, edad);
```

Nombre y edad se le pasan como parametros al WriteLine al final. en la cadena el va a buscar el parametro 0, el encuentra que el parametro 0 es nombre, igual va a buscar el parametro 1 , y va a encontrar el valor de edad.

Así que en lugar de:

```
Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es "+nombre+"y tengo "+edad+" años");
```

Pasa esto:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Mi nombre es {0} y tengo {1} años",nombre, edad);
```